# request shell script to locate longest repeated segment of each line of input

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a large file where each line consists of `24` small integers separated by whitespace. I would like to find, for each line, the longest segment that repeats, allowing the line to `wrap around`. For example, given the line

```
0 10 4 2 7 9 11 8 6 5 0 10 4 2 7 11 9 3 8 3 1 1 6 5
```

the sequence `6 5 0 10 4 2 7` is longest; it has length `7` and the two occurrences are separated by `10` positions (or `14`).

Could someone show me how to cobble a script together to return, for each line, the length of the longest sequence and the interval between its two beginnings?

The way the file is constructed it will be impossible for any segment to be repeated more than once (i.e. more than two appearances), because each number from `0` to `11` is constrained to appear exactly twice.

Much appreciated. --Lloyd

Comment: what did you try?  " "6 5 0 10 4 2 7" is longest; it has length 6". what is length 6?  also You mentioned 2 occurrences are seperated by 10 positions. Did you mean 12 positions i.e 0 10 4 2 7 11 9 3 8 3 1 1?

Comment: Need more examples to better understand the pattern.

Comment: sorry Jack, I somehow wrote length 6 when I meant length=7. I've corrected it. The separation by 10 positions (or 14) is between the starting positions of the two instances of the pattern "6 5 0 10 4 2 7". It occurs once starting at position 8 (considering the line to start with position 0) and again starting at position 22. These two positions are 10 apart, considering the ;line to wrap around (i.e. from position 22 forwards to position 8 is 10 positions). This distance is also 14, if you measure from position 8 forwards to position 22. I don't mind which of these distances is recorded.

Comment: -1 for changing the requirements after several people spent time on answering per your original spec.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of languages that would make this easier than awk ( including gawk ), but here's an all awk answer.

Try putting this into an executable awk file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { DELIM=":" }

function reorder(start) {
    head = ""
    tail = ""
    for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) {
        if( i<start ) tail = sprintf( "%s%s%s", tail, $i, FS )
        else head = sprintf( "%s%s%s", head, $i, FS )
    }

    # last field is the starting index
    return( head tail start )
}

function longest(pair) {
    split( pair, a, DELIM )
    split( a[1], one, FS )
    split( a[2], two, FS )
    long = ""
    for( i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) {
        if( one[i] != two[i] ) break
        long = sprintf( "%s%s%s", long, one[i], FS )
    }
    return( i-1 DELIM two[NF+1]-one[NF+1] DELIM long )
}

{
for( k=1;k<=NF;k++ ) {
    pairs[$k] = (pairs[$k]==""?"":pairs[$k]DELIM) reorder( k )
    }
for( p in pairs ) {
    tmp = longest( pairs[p] )
    out = tmp>out ? tmp : out
    }
print out
}
```

If I call this `awko` then running `awko data` yields data in the form:

```
# of matched fields:index separation:longest match
```

which for the input data is:

```
7:14:6 5 0 10 4 2 7
```

Notice that I haven't bothered to clean up the extra space at the end of the data that matches.  With more input data, I'd have a better idea if this has bugs or not.

---

I wanted to see how fast I could do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { OFS=":" }

function longest(first, second) {
    long = ""
    s = second
    flds = 0
    for( f=first;f<=NF;f++ ) {
        if( $f != $s ) break
        long = sprintf( "%s%s%s", long, $f, " " )
        if( s==NF ) s=0
        s++
        flds++
    }
    return( flds OFS second-first OFS long )
}

{
for(k=1;k<=NF;k++) {
    val = pos[$k]
    if( val!="" ) {
        tmp = longest( val, k )
        delete pos[$k] #### need an awk/gawk that can remove elems or "delete pos" l8r
        }
    else pos[$k] = k
    out = tmp>out ? tmp : out
    }
print out
}
```

It's ~200% faster than the first go round.  It's only using a single outer field loop and processes each matching number as the second is found using the original parsed fields.  Running the same data over and over (2400 lines worth) gave me a system time of 0.33s instead of the 71.10s I got from the first script on the same data.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it works but it is unfortunately too slow for my purposes. I found a faster solution at comp.unix.shell where I posted the same question, but even that will not work for the size of input that I have (26 million lines to read). I will probably just have to write a similar process in C. But thanks again for posting. (And sorry I have no reputation for upvoting.)

Comment: I recognize that this script is far from optimized :) (too many loops). Next time, change the language of your question from `cobble a script together` to something more like `fastest implementation possible`.  Also, if the question had at least 10 different example inputs, it would be easier for posters to generate their own larger test data sets to check for speed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and sorry again if I caused you to waste your time.

Comment: No worries - this is puzzle time for me.  You may already have an answer that's fast enough for you, but I re-worked my efforts and my guess-timate is that the new script would take on the order of an hour for 26 million lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather obfuscated solution that works on a single line of input.  Wrap the whole thing in a loop that reads the line from your input rather than setting it explicitly, and you should have a viable (albeit terribly slow and ugly) solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

input='0 10 4 2 7 9 11 8 6 5 0 10 4 2 7 11 9 3 8 3 1 1 6 5'

trap 'rm -f $TMP1 $TMP2' 0
TMP1=$(mktemp $(basename $0.XXXX))
TMP2=$(mktemp $(basename $0.XXXX))

input="$input $input"  # handle wrap-around
seq 0 11 | while read start_value; do
    echo $input | tr \  \\n | grep -w -n $start_value | sed 's/:.*//' | {
        read i
        read j
        delta=$( expr $j - $i )
        echo $input | tr \  \\n | sed -n "$i,${j}p" > $TMP1
        echo $input | tr \  \\n | sed -n "$j,\$p" > $TMP2
        diff $TMP1 $TMP2 | { IFS=a read length junk
            echo $length $delta $start_value
        }
    }
done | sort -rn | sed 1q | { read length delta start;
    printf "%s " "The sequence"
    echo $input | tr \  \\n | awk '$0==k{t=1}t' k=$start | sed "${length}q"
    echo ' is the longest sequence.' 
    /bin/echo -n The difference between starting positions is $delta '(or ' 
    expr 24 - $delta
    echo ')'
} | tr \\n ' '
echo
```

Comment: Thank you William! I should have made explicit that I was interested in a very fast solution as I have a huge input file (26 million lines to check). See my comment to the poster above. But thanks again for posting -- solutions like yours make me want to get familiar with all the tricks of the trade, even though I probably only end up needing to do something like this every year or two in my work. (And sorry I have no reputation for upvoting.)

Comment: If you need a performant solution, you will need to write something in a language designed for performance.  I would recommend C.